# robocopy command

Tags: svn, robocopy

Iam using robocopy's /MIR command to copy the source files from MKS sandbox to SVN working copy and then iam committing to svn repository.this process is needed becasue we are in the process of changing the source control tool from MKS to Subversion.

```
set mks_path=C:\test
robocopy "C:\test" "C:\testsvn\Source" /MIR /XD "%MKS_PATH%\bin" "%MKS_PATH%\obj" /XF "%MKS_PATH%\project.pj" >>%log%
```

Now the issue is 1) i cant use robocopy \mir command because robocopy /MIR commad  erases files/folders in the destination directory that are no longer in the source directory.
 It deletes all the .svn directory from the SVN working copy, after wards, we cant execute any commands apart from svn checkout.
2) I need to filter few files and folders recursively in the MKS_path, i used /XF and /XD, but its filtering those files and folders from top level.

Please suggest me how can i copy the mks source code to SVN path excluding the files and folders recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using xxcopy also a tool called  [Richcopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx) is good for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you use TortoiseSVN, you can accomplish a "copy from outside the working copy and remove any missing files" action using the [vendor branch here](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.8_releasenotes.html#extlibs) feature.

Simply drag the folder containing the files you want to copy over using the *right* mouse button (i.e. right-click drag) and from the resulting context menu choose "vendor branch here". Then all you need to do is commit the changes.

This feature is intended to track 3rd-party libraries inside your own repository, but conceptually that's basically what you're doing: you're tracking changes in "MKS" inside a folder in your SVN repository.

Answer (score 0):

/MIR is just the combination of /E and /PURGE.
Why not simply use /E and leave out /MIR?